# Change Grid Cells Size in MatplotLib Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib in python to plot data. I want to also show grids and I used `plt.grid(True)`. It shows the grid, but I want to change the size.

I want to show the each cell size of the grid to some user value. How can I change the grid cell size?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the major and minor grid lines like so, assuming a plot of with axis limits going to 20 (obviously, you're going to want to change the numbers to match your plot):

```
import numpy

myplot = ...
major_ticks = numpy.arange( 0, 20, 4 ) # major tick for every 4 units
minor_ticks = numpy.arange( 0, 20, 2 ) # minor tick for every 2 units

myplot.set_xticks( major_ticks )
myplot.set_xticks( minor_ticks, minor=True )
myplot.set_yticks( major_ticks )
myplot.set_yticks( minor_ticks, minor=True )
```